# AWS Ubuntu SSH broken after updating the OpenSSL

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssl, ubuntu-20.04

My Ubuntu machine is running with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020 and i would like to update to OpenSSL 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1, the apt upgrade does not do this so i have to manually download the package and do the make install, so after did the installation i am not able to SSH into my Ubuntu machine but the Serial console is working

i am trying to recover my SSH connection so i have uninstalled all the OpenSSL including the dependencies and removed the folders it shows on whereis openssl.

Below are the steps which is did,

```
1)  openssl version 
2)  sudo apt-get update 
3)  sudo apt-get upgrade
4)  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libssl-dev, and got the message libssl-dev is already the newest version 
5)  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade openssl and got the message openssl is already the newest version 
6)  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/openssl/1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1/openssl_1.1.1f.orig.tar.gz
7)  tar -xzf openssl_1.1.1f.orig.tar.gz
8)  cd openssl-1.1.1f/
9)  sudo ./config
10) Sudo make
11) Sudo make test
12) Sudo make install
13) openssl version, Gives the below error so I did sudo ldconfig 
openssl: symbol lookup error: openssl: undefined symbol: EVP_mdc2, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
14) sudo ldconfig
15) Then I cannot login using SSH.
```

Then i had Removed the OpenSSL completely from the machine and rebooted from the Serial Console, but still the SSH is not working

Comment: did you remove the existing openssl before the install?

Comment: No, i just install the downloaded one from the launchpad.net, it was working fine until i lost my ssh, when i try to reconnect then i am not able to login

Comment: (1) The only Ubuntu with OpenSSL based on 1.1.1f is focal and the current focal version is 1ubuntu2.13 -- why do you want a _less_ safe version? (2) Do you think the version displayed by `openssl version` is the Ubuntu package version? It's not. You almost certainly had 1ubuntu2.13 installed before you broke it. (3) the `orig.tar.gz` file is NOT the Ubuntu package, it is the unpatched upstream, which usually won't work with the rest of your system, especially when you use the generic build process not the (different) Debian/Ubuntu build process.

Comment: i have removed the openssl from the machine completely but still i am not able to SSH to my machine,

Comment: It is a very bad Idea to install the unpatched one, and also please check if the AWS instance is running with particular kernal version as that will give you major cause of the broken SSH, if the base is from a kernal then you don't have any other choice other than to restore it from the backup or AMI..